# Access chef resources inside ruby block

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I've been trying to find the answer to this in the chef docs and through Google, but I've not been able to come up with anything.  I'm not a ruby guy (yet), so the answer to this might stem from my approaching the problem with "just enough ruby for Chef".  Here's what I want to do: in my `deploy` resource, in the `before_migrate` attribute, I want to execute a resource in my current recipe.  What I am doing currently is to just stuff the resource into the block itself, but I know there must be a better way to do it.

```
before_migrate do

    template "#{app_root}/#{applet_name}/local_settings.py" do
        source "local_settings.py.erb"
        owner app_config['user']
        group app_config['group']
        variables(
            :database_name => app_config['postgresql']['database_name'],
            :user => app_config['postgresql']['user'],
            :password => app_config['postgresql']['password']
        )   
        action :create
    end 
end
```

What I'm aiming for is something like

```
before_migrate do
    "template #{app_root}/#{applet_name}/local_settings.py".execute
end
```

So I can re-use that template code.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the great guys in the #chef IRC channel, I solved my problem.  The notification resource needs to be accessed directly, using

`Chef::Resource::Notification.new("template[#{app_root}/#{applet_name}/local_settings.py", :create)`

Which will notify the `template` resource to run the `:create` action.

Comment: The opened square angle bracket is not closed. I believe it should look more like 

Chef::Resource::Notification.new("template[#{app_root}/#{applet_name}/local_settings.py]", :create)

Answer (score 2):

You could specify the resource outside of the "deploy" resource with an action of nothing and then, in the *before_migrate* do something like:

```
    before_migrate do

        ruby_block "notify_template" do
            block do
              true
            end
            action :create
            notifies :create, "template[#{app_root}/#{applet_name}/local_settings.py]", :immediately
        end

     end
```

That way, you can notify it when you need it.