# How can I call a Chef resource from an HWRP?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Maybe this is really simple, and I'm just not understanding something. I want to invoke a Chef resource from within an HWRP that I wrote. In my scenario, I'd like to invoke the [reboot](https://docs.chef.io/resource_reboot.html) resource. How should I go about doing so?

I have tried something like the following:

```
def reboot_system
    wu_reboot = Chef::Resource::Reboot.new('wu_reboot', :reboot_now)
    wu_reboot.run_action(:reboot_now)
end
```

A few things. I am not sure if I should be creating an instance of Chef::Resource::Reboot or Chef::Provider::Reboot. I also don't really understand the second argument listed above..this is supposed to be the "run_context", but I don't know what that is. Finally, I do not know how to set attributes or invoke an action.

I tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14966599/1343005) as a format to go by, but I haven't been able to get it to work so far. Any help understanding would be much appreciated.

EDIT:

I looked at the [source code](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/reboot.rb) and I could just execute this:

```
node.run_context.request_reboot(
      :delay_mins => @new_resource.delay_mins,
      :reason => @new_resource.reason,
      :timestamp => Time.now,
      :requested_by => @new_resource.name
      )
```

However, I don't think this is the best solution. I would like to know how to accomplish invoking the resource instead of bypassing it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find an example of using Chef-Resources inside a HWRP in an older revision of the official Jenkins cookbook (was converted to LWRP in the meantime):

https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/jenkins/blob/v2.0.2/libraries/plugin.rb#L138-L141

Keep in mind, that the Reboot resource is rather new (Chef 12+)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the same way you would in a recipe.  If you need it to run immediately, then you would do:

```
reboot 'now' do
  action :nothing
end.run_action(:reboot_now)
```

Comment: The Chef run throws an exception saying "undefined method `reboot' for #<Chef::Provider::MyClass> etc". Can you be more clear on your solution? For example, I know that this will work with LWRP's if you set "use_inline_resources"

Comment: Hm.  Fair enough.  I guess I've never done a true HWRP.  Have you looked at `poise`.  I'm not sure why you chose and HWRP over and LWRP, but most likely you'll find that poise gives you the best of both worlds.

Comment: I chose an HWRP because I have more native Ruby code in my provider..and it's somewhat of a mess as an LWRP (I tried it originally). I will take a look at poise. Thanks.

Comment: Yea, I bet you'll be very happy with poise.  That is exactly what it is written for.

Answer (score 0):

Within Ruby classes, you don't have access to the Chef DSL, so you have to access the underlying implementation of the resource as a class. The name of the class will be the camelcase-conversion of the resource name. You invoke the action with the run_action method.

Your original version actually was pretty close. You only use the resource, not the provider (because the provider may not even always be the same, depending on your platform).

The run_context is an object that chef uses to pass information to the resource - for instance, you can access node attributes through run_context.node['attributename']. It is already a member variable in your provider (and I think also in the resource object); you can simply pass it in to the constructor for your new resource.

You set attributes through member variables by the same name, and you trigger the actual action with the run_action method.

```
r = Chef::Resource::Reboot.new("wu_reboot", run_context)
r.reason("Because we need a reboot")
r.run_action(:reboot_now)
```